# Output format and quality to be same as input

Tags: ffmpeg

Have many videos different videos of different format and quality in which i need to add small amount of text.

What command should i use to get same file format/quality for output as it was for input ?

Comment: What are the different formats you have?

Comment: .mpg and .mp4. What other data you need ? All are prepared for broadcasting, but some are made long time ago. Visually there is huge difference betwean old and new ones. I do not mind that as long as after i export them, their quality wont be lower then input. Will be broadcasted on cable TV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these are for broadcast play-out over local storage, these commands are biased towards quality and away from filesize.

For MP4s:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "text filters here" -c:v libx264 -crf 8 -c:a copy -map 0 -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

For MPGs:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg -vf "text filters here" -c:v mpeg2video -q:v 2 -c:a copy -map 0 output.mpg
```

Comment: I have moved comments [to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35058/discussion-on-answer-by-mulvya-output-format-and-quality-to-be-same-as-input) as it was getting too verbose.  The old chat is also [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35023/discussion-between-bigbrother2010-and-mulvya).